# How to replace the value of the index of a string in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, split

i am making a project about turing machine and i am having a problem about the how do i replace a character in an certain index of a string

Example: if i input in the initial tape: 
stackoverflow
then code in the inputArea like
write 1
the output should be
1tackoverflow
but sadly the output of my code is
11111111111111

I'm trying to get rid of the loop because i know my loop is the problem but how should i do it ?

Here's my code

runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ActE){

```
    String[] iniTape = iTapeArea.getText().split("");


    String[] input = inputArea.getText().split("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {
        if(input[i].contains("write")==true){
            sub = input[i].substring(6, input[i].length());
             for(int j=0;j<iniTape.length;j++){
        System.out.print(""+iniTape[j].replace(iniTape[j], sub));

            }
        }
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to try this hard. You can use

```
 String str = "stackoverflow";
 System.out.println(str.replace("" + str.charAt(0), "1"));
```

Out put:

```
 1tackoverflow
```

Comment: yes sir, it can be that simple but for example if i code
write 1
write 2
write 3

the output should be

123ckoverflow

Comment: @marky you are giving inputs like this ? "write 1 write 2 write 3" or
"1 2 3" ???

Answer (score 0):

Use **replaceAll()** method of **String class** as below

```
yourString.replaceAll("" + yourString.charAt(index), "1")//index is your index at which you want to replace
```

**""+** is equivalent of doing `String.valueOf(yourString.charAt(index))`

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

> ```
> String[] iniTape = iTapeArea.getText().split("");
> String sub= null;
> String temp = null;
> String[] input = inputArea.getText().split("\n");
> //"test 1\ntest 2\ntest 3".split("\n");
> for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
> {
>     if(input[i].contains("write")==true){
>         sub = input[i].substring(6, input[i].length());
>           iniTape[i+1] = sub;
>     }
> }
> StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
> for(String str : iniTape) {
>   buffer.append(str);
> }
> System.out.println(buffer.toString());
> ```
>
> replace the index value with the required character

Answer (score 0):

I use the replaceFirst(String, String) function of the String class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "stackoverflow";
    s = s.replaceFirst("" + s.charAt(0), "1");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a given certain indexes of a string with that number you can do the following

```
static String str = "stackoverflow";
public static String replaceCharsAt(int ... indices) {
    for (int index : indicies) {
        str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), i+1);
    }
    return str;
}
```